# How to filter Only Organization entities in DetectEntitiesOutput?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk-go, amazon-comprehend

I am new to Go language and trying picking it up , so pardon for any obvious issues but need some help..

Question : I am trying to filter only Organization Entities returned in by Comprehend in DetectEntitiesOutput..

My imports are following

````
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/comprehend"

    func Filter(vs []Entity, f func(Entity) bool) []Entity {
    vsf := make([]Entity, 0)
    for _, v := range vs {
    if f(v) {
    vsf = append(vsf, v)
    }
    }
    return vsf
    }

    func isOrg(vs Entity) bool {
    return strings.EqualFold(Entity.Type, "ORGANIZATION")
    }```


But i am getting following error ./main.go:52:18: undefined: Entity
./main.go:53:16: undefined: Entity
./main.go:62:15: undefined: Entity
./main.go:63:27: undefined: Entity

Can someone help?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler cannot find definition of `Entity` struct. Make sure it's present in the same package or if it's from a different package you would replace `Entity` with `packageName.Entity`.

Comment: I was able to solve this with comprehend.Entity. Thanks